# How do I use different versions of same library for different targets in same conan build?

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I'm dealing with C++ projects that include unit tests with cxxtest, and which are built using CMake. Currently I'm in the process of integrating the use of Conan (using version 1.54 as of now), as we didn't have a proper way of dealing with artifacts and dependencies before. So far I used the basic cmake() generator of Conan, as that seemed the easiest approach, and for building our projects it works reasonably well as of yet.

To put things into perspective, I'm still relatively new to Conan and Cmake, and additionally our use of cmake so far had nothing to do with modern cmake. Therefore I was actually quite happy the basic cmake() generator did the task for now. Now that Conan 2.0 got published officially, things got mixed up again, as there's the new CMakeDeps() generator now, which so far I haven't quite understood, to be honest.

However, here comes the problem: I'm now trying to integrate the cxxtest unit tests into the build, and here I stumbled over a dependency problem, as I'm trying to use different versions of the same library in one build. But, not surprisingly, with conan they always get linked both, when in the same package, causing multiple definitions of course, and I don't know how to solve this:

The project (a `project_lib.a`) depends on two other libs (all static), `depA.a` and `depB.a`. I manage the dependencies with a straightforward cmakefile.py:

```
name = "project"
requires = [("depA/2.1.0.0"),
            ("depB/2.2.0.0")]
settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"

generators = "cmake"
...
```

All is fine with that for the normal build. However, the problem arises when I have to build the unit tests. The thing is, they have the same dependencies, but rely on a special test-build of depA (otherwise the unit tests won't work), which at first I put in a seperate package, so I could add the following code to the conanfile.py:

```
...
options = {
    "cxxtest": [True, False]
}
default_options = {
    "cxxtest": False
}

def configure(self):
    self.options['depA'].cxxtest = self.options.cxxtest
```

The unit tests rely on the project_lib.a as well, of course, so if I first build that, and the unit tests independently after that (installing the test version of depA with conan instead of the normal version), all is good.

What I'm trying to achieve, however, is building it all in one go. So my wishful thinking is, I only have to call `conan install` once, and whatever package I get for depA, it includes both versions of it. But more importantly, during the build I use and link only the respectively needed one, i.e. the normal one to the project_lib, and the test one to the unit tests.

With other words, I'd like to be able to have **target based link_libraries**, based on the "cxxtest" option, which I then can use in the same build, and idealy *without* having to specify them explicitly in the cmake files (i.e. preferably by using target dependend CONAN_LIBS or similar), as one of our reasons to use conan in the first place is to have the explicity of dependencies in the conanfile only.

I know there's stuff you can do e.g. with the cpp_info or the package_info (e.g. regarding components), but I have to admit I couldn't work out if and how that might help, based on the examples in the conan docs, as they don't seem to cover this kind of problem. Therefore here I am.

So, is my wishful idea possible? If so, how, maybe with CMakeDeps? If not, are there proper alternatives? Or should I simply keep on working with two seperate builds (which is ok, but feels like a workaround, which I'd try to avoid whereever possible)?

I hope I have made myself clear, if not, please let me know.

Comment: In general it is not possible that 1 package depends on 2 version of other package at the same time. There might be other approaches, like using conditional requirements (to depend on one or the other, but not both simultaneously). It would be important to understand first the linkage that is happening there, as it is definitely not possible to link two versions of the same thing, but unittests need to be built with the "depa". Probably the best is to file a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, because there it is possible to discuss details better than here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your repsonse, @drodri! Your question regarding the linking hits the spot, I had an error in my assumption (still much to learn about linking, myself has). Contrary to that, project_lib.a is **not** statically linked to DepA. Its lib is not even needed to build it, only the corresponding headers. It's not until the unit tests are linked to become an executable that I need the DepA lib, in that case the test version. So the question is moot, at least in this case, as I can therefore simply use the test version from the beginning for this use case without consequences.